# Can not get n-digits precision with N[expr, n] in WSTP

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I am new to Wolfram Language and wolfram engine. I use wolfram engine development kit to increase the precision of the output from Spherical Bessel function from WSTP in c++. Part of codes that transfer functions and parameters to the link is

```
int order = 1;
long double x = 15;
long double result;
WSPutFunction( lp, "N", 2);
    WSPutFunction( lp, "SphericalBesselY", 2);
        WSPutInteger( lp, order);
            WSPutReal128(lp, x);
                WSPutInteger(lp, 30);
 WSEndPacket( lp);
 WSGetReal128( lp, &result);
    printf( "%.30Lf \n ", result);
```

However, whatever precision number I alter, the result is the same and

Comment: (1) `N[SphericalBesselY[2, x], 30]` will return a machine-precision number if `x` is machine precision. I have not tried quad-precision numbers, but probably it is either unsupported or `N[..]` returns a quad-precision number. For your `N[..]` call to work, the input `x` should be exact or of a high-enough precision that `SphericalBesselY` evalutes to at least `30` digits of precision....

Comment: (2)  From the docs: ["Note that you can conveniently exchange arbitrary-precision numbers with external programs by converting them to lists of digits in the Wolfram Language using IntegerDigits and RealDigits."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HandlingListsArraysAndOtherExpressions.html) It appears you're trying to read a quad-precision FP number, not an arbitrary-precision number.  If `N[..]` works as you seem to intend, it should return an arbitrary-precision number.

Comment: I guess I should add (3) your question ends mid sentence.

Comment: Okay, my first two comments may be wrong if Real128 is supported as it is in [`Import`/`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Real128.html).  Nonetheless, `N[expr, prec]` cannot be used to raise the precision. Also `N[y, newprec]` might not change the underlying point-estimate used to compute the Real128 number (if quad behaves like double). E.g. `N` of the Real128 value of `E` is ``N[2.718281828459045235360287471352662314358421867194`33.71535951436589, 30]`` resulting in ``2.718281828459045235360287471352662314358421867194`30.``, which has exactly the same numerical value.

Comment: thanks, my question then should be directed to how to change the a machine precision digits into arbitrary precision digit and parse to link within WSTP. @MichaelE2

Answer (score 1):

You're feeding it with the same precision so it's hard to expect different results, I think.

In Mathematica itself:

```
SphericalBesselY[1, 15.] // Accuracy
```

will give you 17.35 [decimal] digits of accuracy. I'm not sure how WSTP treats 128bit floating numbers though

By contrast:

```
SphericalBesselY[1, 15.] (* -0.0399761*)
SphericalBesselY[1,15`100] (* telling it 15 is precise up to 100 digits will answer -0.0399761319533241409493242562719989970404441275224595705839764978076\
671781562996219519312380539715616 *)
```

So the problems seems to be with passing arbitrary precision numbers over WSTP.

Probably someone can suggest how to do it.